# Retrieve data from XML Object

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

I'm having a small problem. I parsed an message with an xml2js Parser

```
parser.parseString(message.toString(), function (err,result) {
    //Extract the value from the data element
    value = result;
    console.log(result);
});
return value;
```

This correctly returns an XML object which looks like:

```
{message: { type: ['authMessage'], sender: ['username']} }
```

but know i want the data, meaning type = authMessage; sender = username;

How can i get that data? I'm not really sure, thanks for any help.

Comment: That looks like json, not xml.

Comment: @Danny That's why the OP mentioned he is using an xml2js pParser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've used `parser.parseString()`, you get a plain Javascript object. How about:

```
var type = result.message.type[0];
var sender = result.message.sender[0];
```

Here is [some documentation on Javascript variable types.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not well aware of "asynchronous" and "synchronous" concepts. `console.log(result);` displays the result in the asynchronous callback, which is executed *after* `return value;`. So `value` is not initialized and function returns `undefined`.

This code *may* work if `parseString` does not perform asynchronous calls internally but it is an exceptional situation. Most of the code with callbacks works asynchronously. So you need to organize your code in this manner too.